# WhatsApp Web not working on macOS Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: safari, google-chrome, firefox, whatsapp.app

[WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com) used to work all right. It works fine on my other 2012 MacBook, but not working on my Late 2013 MacBook. When attempting to open the Web app, the QR code continues to load indefinitely.

[image: web.whatsapp]

I have tried with Firefox, Chrome & Safari but the issue persists. I have also tried in Private browsing mode, thinking maybe it's a cache issue but no luck.

How can I salvage this?

Comment: Did you try cleaning browser cookies?

Comment: yes that didn't help

Comment: What about the WhatsApp macOS app?

Comment: Same issue there